# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am using a module Podcast-release in my app as an dependency. that has the following build types defined

```
    buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        useProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
        jniDebuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'

    }
}
```

Similarly, I have the same build types defined in my project.

```
 buildTypes {
    debug {
        versionNameSuffix "-DEBUG"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        resValue "string", "app_name"
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "API_ENV", "\"prod\""
        buildConfigField "String", "CAST_APP_ID", "\"" + castId + "\""
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        debuggable false
        zipAlignEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
```

According to [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#resolve_matching_errors)  this should work since the dependency app and library variants are exactly the same.

> an app's debug variant automatically consumes a library's debug variant, and so on.

Here is the error

> path\build.gradle
>       Error:Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :Podcast-release.
>   Open File
> Show Details
>       Error:Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :Podcast-release.
>   Open File
> Show Details
>       Error:Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :Podcast-release.
>   Open File
> Show Details
>       Error:Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :Podcast-release.
>   Open File
> Show Details
>       Error:Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :Podcast-release.
>   Open File
> Show Details

Comment: Is the Podcast-release module in the same project as your application module? Is it included in the settings.gradle file for the project?

Comment: Yes it is @clownba0t